# Xcode - Move focus to Previous area

Tags: ios, xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying set a shortcut to be able to switch easily between views while I am coding in Assistant Editor. The way to set the shortcut can be found:

```
In Xcode -> Preferences -> KeyBindings -> "Move Focus To ....."
```

My question here is why my

```
 Xcode -> Preferences -> KeyBindings -> "Move Focus To Previous Area"
```

is disabled?

Simple question here, but really useful.
If anyone can investigate and let me know. Did a quick google search but nothing came up.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out, that same as Chrome browser, when you want to switch to the next tab you press:

```
CTRL + TAB
```

Same if you want to go to the tab on the left of the current tab viewing is:

```
CTRL + SHIFT + TAB
```

Same applies for switching between views in the assistant editor in Xcode